# PHP Return response json null

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with returning null when I'm trying to return a response as a JSON. But when I write only `$price = $this->getPrice($clawer);` without return I have price that I want.

```
public function index(){

        $url = 'https://url';
        $product_url = 'product_id';

        $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', $url . '' . $product_url );

        $price = $this->getPrice($crawler);

         return response()->json([
            'result' => $price,
            'data' => 'test'
        ], 200);


    }

    public function getPrice($crawler){
        $price = '';

            if (!$price) {
            return $crawler->filter('#j-sku-price')->each(
            function ($node) {
            $price = $node->text();
            print($price);
            });
        }
        return $price;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed return:

```
 public function getPrice($crawler){
        $price = '';

            if (!$price) {
            return $crawler->filter('#j-sku-price')->each(
            function ($node) {
            $price = $node->text();
            print($price); //Remove this
            return $price; //add this
            });
        }
        return $price;
    }
```

No need to use `response()` if the status code is 200:

```
  return [
            'result' => $price,
            'data' => 'test'
        ];
```